# Conflict with Chrome and fullPage.js

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, uikit, fullpage.js

I'm using [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) and [UIkit](http://getuikit.com/) to build a site. I have noticed that there's a problem on Chrome when I'm implementing an off canvas menu. The menu appears and works in all other browsers, but on Chrome it seems that there's a conflict and I can't see it at all. If I remove the plugin, the menu works fine.

The problem should be related to the `translate3d` properties that the plugin uses.

Here's a [Jsfiddle demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/davis88/97tbk/689/)

Any idea on how can I solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I gave up this option as I didn't manage to find a solution to this problem. So, I used the [mmenu.js](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/) plugin to create the off canvas menu instead of the related UIkit component and the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Don't give up. There is a lot of fun with UIkit and fullPage.js integrated. Add the following to your CSS then you will see the menu:

`.uk-offcanvas-page {
    position:absolute;
}`